# ¿Como realizar una construcción adecuada en un proyecto en React?

Tags: reactjs, npm, build

tengo una gran duda y es que se que antes de enviar un producto a producción hay que realizar la construcción del mismo y tengo mi proyecto con dos carpetas las cuales son cliente y servidor en la cual cada uno tiene su propio archivo package.js, mi duda es como hago para realizar el empaquetamiento de la aplicación completa, respecto a la experiencia que ustedes tienen como se hace en la vida real solo se empaqueta en este caso la carpeta de cliente?
A continuación comparto una imagen de como tengo la organización de mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizo está pregunta ya que el otro día estaba aprendiendo como se empaqueta los archivos para producción pero en el ejemplo solo tenían la carpeta creada con react.

Les agradezco si me pueden sacar de esa duda, gracias.

Comment: espero estés bien. Lo "ideal" siempre va a depender del proyecto, en general en frontend y el backend se trabajan por separado, por lo que lo normal sería subir el Backend y asignarle un dominio (o también puede ser un subdominio tipo api.tudominio.com), y así luego desde el frontend únicamente te encargas de hacer las llamadas a la API. Trabajarlos por separado también te evita tener que reinicializar el backend en caso de actualizar o hacer mejoras en el front, y viceversa. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta pregunta puede depender mucho del tipo de proyecto, pero personalmente te puedo hacer una sugerencia...

En principio la API y la APP van separadas tal cual como lo tienes, ahora bien sería bueno que sigas la siguiente recomendación a lo largo de tu proyecto.

No se si has escuchado hablar del termino Clean Architecture el cual viene del libro de Rober C. Martin (Oncle Bob), resulta que esta se basa en organizar el código por capas acuñando el termino de Arquitectura Hexagonal por su forma tipo "cebolla":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este tema puede irse bien largo, te recomiendo que te informes más a fondo pero te resumire el tema de la forma más simple a modo ejemplo.

Imaginate que estás creando una app resulta que para dividir la app por capas tendrás que tener dentro de src/app la siguiente estructura:

```html
Core/
     Components/
       dump/
         dump-component.html
         dump-component.css
         dump-component.ts
         dump-component.spec.ts
     Types/
     Utils/
features/
   random-feature
     Application/ 
       use-case.ts
     Domain/
        interface.ts
     Infraestructure/
        repository.ts
     UI/
       component.html
       component.ts
       component.spec.ts
       component.css
app.ts
app.css
app.html
```

En core irá toda esa parte de la app que se comparte entre diferentes componentes y/o se usa globalmente.

En features irás todas las funcionalidades de tu app (Lo puedes dividir por paginas, recuerda que los componentes que se usan aquí son los que se van a mostrar directamente en la página y en core irán esos componentes "tontos".

Obviamente tendrás que tener en cuenta como conectar todo desde crear una interfaz, la insfraestructura y luego el caso de uso que es el que vas a llamar desde la UI.

Te invito a que estudies más a fondo del tema porque realmente puede ser un poco complicado al principio pero luego verás que será una de las mejores cosas que vas a aprender.

Algunas fuentes que podrías visitar:

- [Hexagonal architecture (software)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software))

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda amigo, buscare más sobre el tema.

Comment: De nada, espero y te sirva de mucho.